# Reading from in-memory Access Database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, c#-4.0

Please could someone show me a few examples of reading from an in-memory Access database (i.e. uploaded to a website) in C# / .NET 4.0.

Comment: Why is this not a real question? It's real - it happens that the answer is simple - you can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - OLEDB will need a real file connection. Instead, save the Access database to the file system, use the OLEDB connection and command classes to work with the database.